# Close Connection and Keep Executing

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

How can I return a 400 status code and close the connection, without aborting script execution? I'm looking to initiate execution of the script using `<cfhttp>` but not wait for the script to end before returning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run the portion of the script you want to keep running after the connection is close, on a different thread.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/749-Learning-ColdFusion-8-CFThread-Part-II-Parallel-Threads.htm) on how to launch a new thread in Coldfusion.

Comment: Long before <cfthread> there was a way to do this (I had some code that did this, but I cant remember.) <cfthread> is clearly the right way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hit a new request triggered from in another request without waiting just set the cfhttp timeout to 0 and it will return right away without waiting on response. For continuing a script after returning a separate thread may be a better idea but if you are hitting something outside the server or really need a separate request then cfhttp timeout=0 should do the trick.